# Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser

Tags: selenium, junit

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:109)
    at com.java.abs.Top.setUp(Top.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:109)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:103)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:272)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.start(HttpCommandProcessor.java:234)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:100)
    ... 25 more
```

I used

```
Junit -4
selenium-java-2.42.2
selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0
 & Firefox Setup 42.0
```

But still getting that error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run FF 39.0 or above then add selenium-2.43.0 jars to the project. if FF 47.0 or above then use selenium-2.53.0 jars along with marionette.

First, you can execute hello world program with the combination of both selenium-2.43.0, FF 42.0 and JUnit(At least one test annotation) if it is working then run your actual program with same combination.

Comment: is normal hello world program executing with the combination? if not what is the exact error message.

Comment: @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
   selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox C:\\Users\\mhapuge\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "https://www.google.com");
   selenium.start();
  }

Comment: @Test
  public void testKkk() throws Exception {
   selenium.captureEntirePageScreenshot("C:\\Users\\mhapuge\\Desktop\\screenshots\\cdfdfobjdjf.png", "");
  }

Comment: @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
   selenium.stop();
  }
 
}

Comment: this is my programme. So I used FF 42.0, selenium-java-2.43.0, selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0 . But it gives same error

Comment: you can use this code to start firefox.    WebDriver d1=new FirefoxDriver();
  d1.manage().window().maximize();
  d1.get("https://www.google.co.in/"); and then you can write your script. if you want to run program using stand-alone-server then i wll share core for that

Comment: But it gives "java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser at "

Comment: I think you haven't start selenium-standalone server. you need to start the server to execute the program.

Comment: I have already started selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0 by using cmd :/

Comment: DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
  caps.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);
  caps.setBrowserName("firefox");
  URL urlhub=new URL("http://172.16.10.54:4444/wd/hub");
  RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(urlhub, caps);                you can specify your own ip address and platform.